# fetch data from two tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

i want to get details of user and vendor in order list.

`@Entity
public class Orders {

```
@Id 
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
private String order_id;
private String amount;
private Date date;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id",referencedColumnName="vendor_id", nullable = false)
private Vendor vendor;

public String getOrder_id() {
    return order_id;
}
public void setOrder_id(String order_id) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
@JsonBackReference(value = "user")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
@JsonBackReference(value = "vendor")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
public Vendor getVendor() {
    return vendor;
}
public void setVendor(Vendor vendor) {
    this.vendor = vendor;
}
```

}
`

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id 
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String user_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String user_name;
    private String password;
    private Date dob;
    private String email_id;
    private String mobile;
    private String location;
    
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "user")
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<Orders> OrderList = new ArrayList<>();

    
    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }
    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }
    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }
    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getEmail_id() {
        return email_id;
    }
    public void setEmail_id(String email_id) {
        this.email_id = email_id;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    public List<Orders> getOrderList() {
        return OrderList;
    }
    public void setOrderList(List<Orders> orderList) {
        OrderList = orderList;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [first_name=" + first_name + ", last_name=" + last_name + ", user_name=" + user_name
                + ", password=" + password + ", dob=" + dob + ", email_id=" + email_id + ", mobile=" + mobile
                + ", location=" + location + "]";
    }
    
    
    

}
```

```
@Entity
public class Vendor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String vendor_id;
    private String v_name;
    private String v_address;
    private String v_email;
    private String v_password;
    private String v_mobile;
    private String v_image;
    private String package_detail;
    private String price;
    private String service_name;
    
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "vendor")
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="vendor",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<Orders> OrderList = new ArrayList<>();

    
    
     @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    public List<Orders> getOrderList() {
        return OrderList;
    }
    public void setOrderList(List<Orders> orderList) {
        OrderList = orderList;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getService_name() {
        return service_name;
    }
    public void setService_name(String service_name) {
        this.service_name = service_name;
    }
    public String getVendor_id() {
        return vendor_id;
    }
    public void setVendor_id(String vendor_id) {
        this.vendor_id = vendor_id;
    }
    public String getV_name() {
        return v_name;
    }
    public void setV_name(String v_name) {
        this.v_name = v_name;
    }
    public String getV_address() {
        return v_address;
    }
    public void setV_address(String v_address) {
        this.v_address = v_address;
    }
    public String getV_email() {
        return v_email;
    }
    public void setV_email(String v_email) {
        this.v_email = v_email;
    }
    public String getV_password() {
        return v_password;
    }
    public void setV_password(String v_password) {
        this.v_password = v_password;
    }
    public String getV_mobile() {
        return v_mobile;
    }
    public void setV_mobile(String v_mobile) {
        this.v_mobile = v_mobile;
    }
    public String getV_image() {
        return v_image;
    }
    public void setV_image(String v_image) {
        this.v_image = v_image;
    }
    public String getPackage_detail() {
        return package_detail;
    }
    public void setPackage_detail(String package_detail) {
        this.package_detail = package_detail;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vendor [vendor_id=" + vendor_id + ", v_name=" + v_name + ", v_address=" + v_address + ", v_email="
                + v_email + ", v_password=" + v_password + ", v_mobile=" + v_mobile + ", v_image=" + v_image
                + ", package_detail=" + package_detail + ", price=" + price + ", service_name=" + service_name + "]";
    }
    
    

}
```

```
@Query(value = "select od.* from orders od join vendor ve on(od.vendor_id=ve.vendor_id) where od.vendor_id=?",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Orders> findOrderByVendorId(String vendor_id);



type here
```

i get this as answer

```
 {
        "order_id": "01221903-86ba-41b9-a8b7-0c9498b6441a",
        "amount": "150000",
        "date": "2023-04-01"
 },
```

and i want

```
 {
        "order_id": "01221903-86ba-41b9-a8b7-0c9498b6441a",
        "amount": "150000",
        "date": "2023-04-01"
        "user_id":"as3454r344r",
        "user_name":"xyz",
        "v_name":"abc"
 },
```

Comment: And what is your question for us?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom response class and use jpql to retrieve data.

There is an example over there;

```
@Query(value = "select new <your_package_path>.CustomOrderResponse(o.order_id,o.amount,o.date,u.user_id,u.user_name,v.v_name) " +
        "from Orders o, User u, Vendor v " +
        "where o.User.user_id = u.user_id "+
        "and o.Vendor.vendor_id = v.vendor_id"+
        "and o.vendor_id=?")
public List<CustomOrderResponse> findOrderByVendorId(String vendor_id);
```